# How to keep certain thread delay between requests and store correlation id for all the request during load test

Tags: jmeter

May i know how to achieve this scenario in JMeter.

Requirement 1 : Request 1 should execute for 15 mins, once 15 mins crossed request 2 should execute and request 1 to be stopped.

Requirement 2 : In request 1, we need to capture all dynamic value and store it some place and same dynamic value we should use it as request body for request 2. We like to run large numbers of users. Not sure, how to store all the response in some files or other alternatives.

Ex : Request 1 - > Trigger -> Store response somewhere(15 min run & 100 iteration) - stopped
Request 2 - > Trigger after 15 min - Execute request with above 100 iteration response)

Answer (score 0):

1. Either take a look at [Runtime Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller), using this guy you can choose how long its child(ren) will be run or just put your requests 1 and 2 into separate [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
2. If you want to store full responses into a file take a look at:

   - [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to capture the required part of the response into a JMeter Variable
   - [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property to tell JMeter to save this variable into .jtl results file
   - [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#writer) if you want to write the values into a separate file